# Websphere Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource

Tags: hibernate, datasource, websphere-7

Hi I'm trying to connecting my app to a Datasource defined in Websphere; the datasources is working very well when I do "Test Connection" in Websphere. But when I try the conecction with the app I have this problem in the log:

*java org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ProductDerivations
[8/8/14 16:19:09:520 CST] 00000018 SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.persistence.WsJpaProductDerivation:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.persistence.WsJpaProductDerivation
[8/8/14 16:23:15:269 CST] 0000002c SystemErr     R Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource*

Here I add the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/cmsPrueba</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="use_outer_join">true</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>                                     


    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>

    <!-- Mapping Files -->

    <mapping resource="sisa/cms/db/mapping/CmsFaq.hbm.xml"/>
```

In websphere I defined the datasource with this JNDI: "jdbc/cmsPrueba"; and I tried this form:

java:comp/env/jdbc/cmsPrueba

and this one:

jdbc/cmsPrueba

I'm using :

- Websphere 7
- Hibernate 2
- JDK 6

This is the web.xml:

```
<display-name>Sisa Admin Panel</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.handleViewExpiredOnClient</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
        <param-value>40000000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>HibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>sisa.cms.admin.util.HibernateThreadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.rface</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>sisa.resources.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/image/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jspx</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jspx</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>APROBADOR</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>EDITOR</role-name>
</security-role>


<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error-404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using JPA annotations anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add resource reference to your web.xml like this:

```
<resource-ref>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/cmsPrueba</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
      <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

In WebSphere define datasource with the JNDI name: `jdbc/cmsPrueba`

You will need to bind this resource reference to JNDI name either during installation or by `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file. If you want to use bind file just add to it the following line:

```
<resource-ref name="jdbc/cmsPrueba" binding-name="jdbc/cmsPrueba" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gas:  I created the file ibm-web-bnd.xml.Now I have this error in the browser : Error 500: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource incompatible with javax.sql.DataSource.                                               and the log not found the DS: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource

Comment: This might be related to classloader issues. Ensure that you dont have database driver jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder, or other jee related jars, which are provided by server.